# PostgreSQL double-quoted type

Tags: postgresql

Can anybody tell me, why double-quoted types behave differently in PosqtgreSQL?

```
CREATE TABLE foo1 (pk int4); -- ok
CREATE TABLE foo2 (pk "int4"); -- ok
CREATE TABLE foo3 (pk int); -- ok
CREATE TABLE foo4 (pk "int"); -- fail: type "int" does not exist
CREATE TABLE foo5 (pk integer); -- ok
CREATE TABLE foo6 (pk "integer"); -- fail: type "integer" does not exist
```

I can't find anything about it in documentation. Is this a bug?
Any information would be greatly appreciated

Comment: I _assume_ that's because `int` and `integer` are just synonyms that get translated to `int4` probably in an early parsing stage before the type is checked. But `"int"` being a quoted identifier is not replaced in that stage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Double quotes mean that an identifier is to be interpreted exactly as written. They cause case to be preserved instead of flattened, and they allow what would otherwise be a keyword to be interpreted as an identifier.

PostgreSQL's `int` is a parse-time transformation to the `integer` type. There is not actually any data type named `int` in the system catalogs:

```
regress=> select typname from pg_type where typname = 'int';
 typname 
---------
(0 rows)
```

It is instead handled as a parse-time transformation much like a keyword. So when you protect it from that transformation by quoting it, you're telling the DB to look for a real type by that name.

This can't really be undone in a backward compatible way, since it'd break someone's system if they created a type or table named `"int"`. (Types and tables share the same namespace).

This is similar to how `user` is transformed to `current_user`. Rails developers often use `User` as a model name, which causes Rails to try to `SELECT * FROM user;` in the DB, but this is transformed at parse time to `SELECT * FROM current_user;`, causing confused users to wonder why their table has a single row with their username in it. Query generators should *always quote identifiers*, i.e. they should be generating `SELECT * FROM "user";`... but few do.